# Inverting a band matrix

Tags: algorithms, linear-algebra, sparse-matrices

I have a [band matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix) -- a sparse, square, symmetric $N \times N$ matrix whose structure looks like the following:

[image: band matrix]

Here, the area under the blue stripes is the non-zero elements; everything else is zero

Is there an algorithm to invert this kind of matrix that is simple yet more efficient than Gaussian elimination and LU decomposition?

Comment: Those matrices are called [band matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix) (and as far as I'm aware, they were the original motivation for finding the [bandwidth of a graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_bandwidth)), and possibly [this paper](http://faculty.nps.edu/pstanica/research/2013JCAM_BandedMatr.pdf) might be a useful starting point.

Comment: @G.Bach Thanks, I'll have a look at the paper. Could you tell me the computational complexity of the method?

Comment: Sorry, don't know, googled for a minute or two but from the abstract it seemed like a promising start.

Comment: @G.Bach Thanks, though. The information of the matrix name is quite helpful.

Comment: Do you want to invert it, or do you want to solve the linear system? The answer is probably the latter, because the inverse of a band matrix is usually dense. Additional question: Is there any more structure to exploit?

Comment: @Pseudonym I want to invert it. I think this is just a general band matrix and right now I don't find more structure to explore.

Comment: OK. The reason why I ask is that in most cases, people who think they want to invert a matrix probably don't. Either way, it's a good question!

Comment: How many diagonals are non-zero? Is the matrix Toeplitz, too?

Answer (score 12):

Since none of the comments gave the concrete answer, I'll write it explicitly here in case anyone needs it (like I did).

Firstly, unfortunately, the inverse of a band-limited matrix is a full (non-band-limited) matrix in general, so just filling out the entries of the inverse matrix would take $\Omega\left(n^2\right)$. So I'll assume you just want to solve a linear system $A x = b$.

Using the algorithm in [this paper](http://faculty.nps.edu/pstanica/research/2013JCAM_BandedMatr.pdf), a general band-limited matrix $A$ of size $n \times n$ with bandwidth $k$ can be decomposed into triangular $k$-bandwidth matrices $L$ and $U$ in $O \left( k^2 n \right)$ time. From there, $L U x = b$ can be solved quickly in $O(k n)$ time. So overall, the runtime will be $O\left(k^2 n\right)$. As a followup, if $k$ is constant, that means that the system can be solved in linear time (highly useful).